# send in link id of username symfony2

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, swiftmailer

want to send an email from my Symfony2 application, this email must contain a link of confirmation and when the user clicks on this link the state of a field in DB to change.

i have  this in my controller:

```
 $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
                                    ->setSubject('demande de conge ')
                                    ->setFrom($col->getEmailCollaborateur())
                                    ->setTo($form->get("emailcdp")->getData())
                                    ->setBody($this->render('AcmeBundle:Conge:demandeCongeNormal.html.twig', array('conge' => $conge, 'id'=> $this->getUser()->getId())))
                                    ;
                                    $this->get('mailer')->send($message);
```

in the twig :

```
id de collab: {{ id }}
```

pour confirmer la demande :

{{ url('confirmer_conge' ,{'username': ' id '}) }}

but in the Email i have this :

```
  http://local.symfony2.com/app_dev.php/confirm/?username=+id+
```

i want to get the id of user that send the message in another controller for update my DB

in my routing.yml:

```
 confirmer_conge:
pattern:  /confirm/{username}
defaults: { _controller: acmeBundle:Conge:confirme }
```

and in the controller i have this function:

```
 public function confirmeAction()
{return $this->render('acmeBundle:Conge:confirmer.html.twig');
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that user is logged?

Comment: yes suree i can open it the problem is how to get the id of user who send the message?

Comment: Ok, so please show me definition of `confirmer_conge` route.

Comment: confirmer_conge:
    pattern:  /confirm/{username}
    defaults: { _controller: acmeBundle:Conge:confirme }

Comment: and the controller :: public function confirmeAction()
    {return $this->render('acmeBundle:Conge:confirmer.html.twig',array('conge'=>$item));
    }

Comment: Too big mess in comments. Please update your question with route definition and your controller action code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the quotes from around id, it is a variable.

```
{{ url('confirmer_conge', {'username': id}) }}
```

As for accessing the ID in your controller it should work like this:

```
public function confirmeAction($username)
    //...
}
```

Comment: please how can i get this id  in my controller (when the other user open the link)

Comment: @lala I updated my answer.  You should read the symfony docs, they are very good.